# modifying the after method in calender class to return true when greater than equal to instead of strictly greater

Tags: java, inheritance, calendar

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class exercise4 {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Calendar cal1 = new CalendarSubclass();
    cal1.setTime(new Date());
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    Calendar cal2 = new CalendarSubclass();
    cal2.setTime(new Date());
    System.out.println(cal2.after(cal1));
    System.out.println(cal1.after(cal2));
    System.out.println(cal1.after(cal1));
    System.out.println(cal2.after(cal2));
    }
}

class CalendarSubclass extends Calendar {
    @Override
    public boolean after(Object when) {
        if (when instanceof Calendar && super.compareTo((Calendar) when) == 0) {
        //if (when instanceof Calendar && ((Calendar) when).toString().equals(this.toString())) {
        //if (when instanceof Calendar && equals((Calendar) when)) {        
        //          System.out.println("lala");
            return true;
        }
        return super.after(when);
    }
@Override
public int compareTo(Calendar anotherCalendar) {
    return compareDays(this.getFirstDayOfWeek(), anotherCalendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
}

private int compareDays(int currentFirstDayOfWeek, int anotherFirstDayOfWeek) {
    return (currentFirstDayOfWeek > anotherFirstDayOfWeek) ? 1
            : (currentFirstDayOfWeek == anotherFirstDayOfWeek) ? 0 : -1;
}

}
```

The output is :

```
false, false, true, true
```

but it should be

```
true, false, true, true
```

since I have overrode the after method using CalenderSubclass.

Edit: When I deleted the compareTo and compareDays method it works, but I am only allowed to modify the after method!

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce. Even if I add empty implementations for the remaining methods I get `true, false, true, true`. Please note that the wrong result comes from `cal2.after(cal1)`, which should be true even with the original `Calender` class!

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` and/or other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your update I can see what causes the problem:

The overriden `compareTo(Calendar anotherCalendar)` is an invalid implementation for the `Calendar.compareTo` method. The documentation for the [`Calendar.compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo-java.util.Calendar-) method states:

> Compares the time values [..] represented by two Calendar objects.

But the overriding method clearly does something else (it compares the "firstDayOfWeek" field, which only makes sense for `Calendar` instances configured for different locales.)

If you can: run away and seek shelter from such broken code!

---

If you can't: reimplement what the original calendars `compareTo` method does:

```
@Override
public boolean after(Object when) {
    if (when instanceof Calendar) {
        Calendar other = (Calendar) when;
        return getTimeInMillis() >= other.getTimeInMillis();
    }
    return super.after(when);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Three suggestions:

1. Use classes from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and those only. Don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated.
2. Make a utility method for this rather than using subclassing.
3. Give your utility method a name that clearly distinguishes it from the `after` method of `Calendar`. Calling it `after` will lead a lot of programmers to believe that it has the same semantics as the existing `after` method, meaning strictly after. You risk a great confusion.

So for example:

```
public static boolean isBeforeOrOn(Instant i1, Instant i2) {
    return ! i1.isAfter(i2);
}

public static boolean isOnOrAfter(Instant i1, Instant i2) {
    return ! i1.isBefore(i2);
}
```

Let’s try them out:

```
    Instant i1 = Instant.now();
    Instant i2 = i1.plusSeconds(1);
    System.out.println("i2 is on or after i1? " + isOnOrAfter(i2, i1));
    System.out.println("i1 is on or after i2? " + isOnOrAfter(i1, i2));
    System.out.println("i1 is on or after i1? " + isOnOrAfter(i1, i1));
    System.out.println("i1 is before or on i2? " + isBeforeOrOn(i1, i2));
    System.out.println("i2 is before or on i2? " + isBeforeOrOn(i2, i2));
```

Output:

> ```
> i2 is on or after i1? true
> i1 is on or after i2? false
> i1 is on or after i1? true
> i1 is before or on i2? true
> i2 is before or on i2? true
> ```

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: I couldn't really spare much time over the OP's comment and the question had changed since I answered as well. Hence chose to delete the answer you commented upon.